# Using SizeConst and SizeParamIndex in Custom Marshaler?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm currently trying to implement a Custom Marshaler for UTF-8 C Strings.
The problem is, that the strings i'm dealing with are not neccesarily null terminated, so i need to rely on their constant size or a size parameter.
When Marshaling them as LPStr i can use the SizeParamIndex and SizeConst MarshalAs Attribute parameters, but i don't seem to have access to those inside my implementation of ICustomMarshaler.

I'd like to avoid using Byte[] and manual UTF-8 conversion on each function, but it seems like that's the only way?
Or am i missing some way to get access to the SizeParamIndex/SizeConst information?
And even if i could somehow pass this data inside the marshaler, how would i get the actual size value for a SizeParamIndex?

Comment: You cannot make this work.  The only back-up plan is to marshal it as IntPtr.

Comment: I'm marshaling them as LPArray into a Byte[] now, saves me the conversion from IntPtr, or is there a problem with that, like .NET trying to free the pointer if it's a parameter to a delegate callback?